# Restore a backup site with Drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, backup, wamp

I'am trying to restore a backup site from a copy made by `Backup and Migrate` module in Drupal, I followed those steps:

1. copy the drupal files to www directory
2. create a new mySQL database
3. install drupal using the new db
4. enable backup and migrate module
5. performed the restore

I faced this error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: files in theme_backup_migrate_file_list() (line 954 of .../sites/default/modules/backup_migrate/backup_migrate.module)
```

the issue was solved by the dev version of "Backup and Migrate" module.

after creating a backup with the dev version and restore it with the same version (dev) in the host machine I get nothing as result, nothing was changed my site still virgin and nothing in `admin/reports/dblog`.

There are possible missing setting that be probable issue cause:

1. DB setting : I have the same setting (db name , table prefix ...)
2. php.ini `memory_limit = 128M` and my backup file is 126M
3. Appache module `mod_rewrite` is enabled

Any Helpful hint please. I don't know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to:

1. Copy files to www
2. Use phpMyAdmin or similar tool to create empty database and import dump B&M created.
3. Change /sites/default/settings.php to connect to your new database.
4. Login to back-end and check on Configuration -> Media -> File system are all necessary paths writable to drupal. Just click "Save configuration" and if none of the fields get red border then it's ok. If some does then you have to change dir access flags (owner, what ever) to make those dirs writable.

Comment: thank you for your response,I used to do it manually like you said, but I want a solution for non professional user admin. Any way I find the issue cause : the setting `memory_limit = 128M` should be also in wamp/bin/php/php.ini, I used to make any modification to the file opened by wamp interface php->php.ini and this is located under wamp/bin/apache, sorry I am newbie and Idk where exactly to made such modif