# Drupal 7 restore from mysql database not working

Tags: mysql, drupal

I had a Drupal 7 website (I think it was version 7.5x, where I don't know "x") that got scrambled.  I have the mysql file "sql.gz" from before it got destroyed and I'm trying to bring back the site.  My webhost only lets me install Drupal 7.67 now, so I created a new site in 7.67.

I tried importing the backup.sql.gz file into the database of the new Drupal 7.67 install using PhpMyAdmin.  The new site was unchanged (it had none of the content I'm trying to restore).

Then I tried to empty all of tables in the new database using PhpMyAdmin before I did the import.  This killed the new site... so I reinstalled Drupal 7.67 again.

Is it possible to restore my content?  If not, is there a way to at least view the text of some of the articles so I can copy out the critical bits that I need?

A related question: [Restore a backup site with Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034317/restore-a-backup-site-with-drupal)

Comment: I cross-posted on Drupal.org and am generating some discussion there: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2019-08-09/drupal-7-restore-from-mysql-database-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Gisle at the Drupal forums guided me to the answer, which was to fix the $prefix and run update.php.  The prefix in settings.php must match and prefix that's on all of the mysql databases in phpMyAdmin.  [See the thread here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2019-08-09/drupal-7-restore-from-mysql-database-not-working#comment-13217185).